# Application breakage showing error of moles on server

Tags: asp.net, .net-assembly, windows-server-2008-r2, pex-and-moles

I have an application (asp.net) which has referenced Moles.On development environment it is working fine but after deployment it breaks randomly giving the follwoing error-

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Moles.Framework, Version=0.94.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Do I need to do any kind of installation on server? If so why is it working fine for sometime and then breaking randomly?

Also I tried setting "CopyLocal" to true. Didn't help.

What else should I try?I am totally clueless.

Comment: Try to unblock assembly or .dll file after deployment if it is blocked. Right-click the file, Properties and click "Unblock".